Norms in the product of ultrametric space
In classical setting in $\mathbb{R}^n$ one can define many different norms for ex. max norm, $l^p$ norm etc. I am just curious what are the possible norms in product of ultrametric spaces for ex. $\mathbb{Q}_{p}\times \mathbb{Q}_{p}\cdots \times\mathbb{Q}_{p}$. As the space is totally disconnected and ultrametric space so the open balls are either disjoint or contained in each other. So it's difficult to visualize the open sets for me in different norms. On the same line what are the different norms one can have on the adelic space $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{Q}_{p_1}\times \mathbb{Q}_{p_2}\cdots\times \mathbb{Q}_{p_l}\times\mathbb{Z}_{p_1}\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}_{p_l}$.

There are again many norms. A natural choice is to take the max norm since it remains an ultrametric.

for other norms it does't remain ultrametric? I am having difficulty to visualize other norms in that setting

All norms over a finite dimensional ultrametric vector space are equivalent, so it's probably best to take the max norm as it seems to be the easiest and most natural to work with.
For the visualization question, if you are comfortable with the pictures in this answer then here is a way to build on that from $\mathbb{Q}_p$ to $\mathbb{Q}_p^n$.
You can picture $\mathbb{Q}_p^n$ as having $p^n$ distinct branches off each platform, one for each length $n$ string you can make from $p$ digits. This collapses back down to the $n=1$ case where digits are simply length $1$ strings. Admittedly, this looks essentially the same as unramified extensions in the link above.
Keep in mind, this really does coincide with the topology of the max norm. For instance we can write vectors in $\mathbb{Z}_p^2$ as $(x_0,y_0) + (x_1,y_1)p + (x_2,y_2)p^2 + \cdots$ and think of these vector coefficients like we would digits in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ or as length $2$ "strings".
Two elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p^2$ are exactly $p^{-k}$ apart (under the typical definition of the max norm) when they share exactly $k$ consecutive starting "coefficient vectors" or "length $n$ strings".
It may help to consider a more concrete example: $\mathbb{Z}_3^2$ can be written as a disjoint union of the $9$ balls $(a,b)+3\mathbb{Z}_3^2$ for $a,b\in \{0,1,2\}$. Any two elements from these distinct cosets are kept separated by a distance of $1/3$ by the max norm.
As for the adelic question, I don't see any particular reason why this same image can't also be extended work except instead of length $n$ strings with $p$ choices for each place, you now have a different number of choices. I imagine there are difficulties with $\mathbb{R}$, however I haven't thought it through.

For your first sentence, don't you need that the base field is complete w.r.t. its ultrametric value?

Thanks for the answer
